# How to debug an XPages application in Bluemix?

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I have deployed an XPages app to bluemix and untill now I have not come further than an Error 500 message.

The error page does not seem to come up. I can not access log.nsf. Can I bring in openlog.nsf?

I am not sure what my options are so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on your application in the Bluemix dashboard
In the left menu there will be an entry 'Logs'
There you see your log files, via dropdowns you can narrow down your log by logtype or channel,

Comment: This includes all the typical domino console output. You can filter the logs as well using the combobox. Select "application" to see just the domino logs